# Problem in QT Quick Test for QML application

Tags: qml, qt-creator

I have a problem in QT Quick Test for QML application, when I add import in my file.qml like:

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtTest 1.0
import ValueField 1.0   <---
import "../myFile.qml"   <--- 

TestCase{

myFile{
id: 
}

}:
```

When I execute my project, I have this problem:

```
module "ValueField" is not installed
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no Ubuntu packages in the [repositories](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=vivid&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=ValueField.qml) providing ValueField.qml.

I'd just remove the `import ValueField 1.0` line in your test file.

Comment: I have a QML file and I want to test the function of this test , in this file I have some import like import ValueField 1.0 , import MyModule 1.0 and I need this imports

So when I run the QT Quick Test for qml application,a have this error:

module "MyModule" is not installed

How to resolved this probleme, for pass my test ??

Comment: @aryan if ValueField is a module that you created then try a relative or an absolute import path.

Comment: its a Module but how to try a  relative or an absolute import path in Qt Creator ?

Comment: @aryan Check http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-imports.html